# What does single quote / apostrophe (') mean after function names in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In my functional programming class, the lecturer created the function `reverse` to take a list and return a list with the same elements but in reverse order:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse [] = []
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
```

However, in the book I am learning from the define they create the same function with ' after the function's name:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' [] = []
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

I was wondering if these two functions behave in the same way, or if the ' alters their behavior? Furthermore, are there cases where one notation is better than the other? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can think `'` suffix as a second version notation by a general convention among Haskell coders just like `reverse_v2`. In the book that you read there must have been a mention of the original `reverse` and `reverse'` is just indicating another (or the *next*) version showing how else it could be or is implemented

Comment: It doesn't "mean" anything, it's just a character that is legal to use in the names of values. It is indeed convention to use a "tick" at the end of a function name to denote a slightly modified version of a previously defined function, but this is nothing other than convention - the apostrophe character has no intrinsic meaning in the Haskell language.

Comment: Almost: `'` cannot be the *first* character in name, as `Char` literals are indicated by a single character in single quotes. `'c'`